# Add new row in a table after each row

Tags: jquery, displaytag

Table:

```
<table id='t1' style='border:1px solid #000000'>
    <tr>
      <td><span id='flight_1'>1</span></td><td>1</td>
    </tr>   

    <tr>
      <td><span id='flight_2'>2</span></td><td>2</td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td><span id='flight_99'>99</span></td><td>99</td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

I want to search for each 'flight_xx' id and then create a new row after the
row belonging to the 'flight_xx' id.

Is this possible using jQuery?

The table is created using the DisplayTag library and I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('span[id^="flight"]').closest('tr').after('<tr>This is a new tr</tr>');
```

That would add a new row after rows that contain spans having ids that start with `flight`.

Comment: Thanks all! So fast! Saves my day.

Answer (score 2):

Standard jQuery would look like:

```
var search  = 99,
    new_row = '<tr><td></td></tr>';

$('#flight_' + search).closest('tr').after(new_row);
```

Comment: This would append a `<tr>` inside a `<span>` :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#flight_" + flightNumber).closest('tr')
                            .after('<tr><td><New Cell!</td><td></td></tr>');
```

This takes the flgiht number, converts it into the `flight_xx` ID, finds that element, goes up to the `<tr>` it's in (via [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), and inserts the new row [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) that one.

If you had the option of adding the ID on the row instead of the `<span>`, do that and just remove the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) call.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with a custom Decorator. Using `startRow()` you can add something by before any row you choose. Something like:

```
    public String startRow() {
    ...

    Item rowItem = (Item) getCurrentRowObject();

    if (rowItem has some value) {
        returnString = "<tr><td>some text here</td></tr>";
    }

    ...

    return returnString;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a custom decorater and override finishRow method.this code will add a row after each row of displayTag table

```
    public  String finishRow()
                         {
                     String  returnString=null; 
                     ActorData rowItem = (ActorData) getCurrentRowObject();
                     if (rowItem.getAnyProperty()!=null )
                        {
                     returnString = "<tr><td>some text here</td><td colspan='2s'>avi</td>"
                    + "</tr>";
                         }
                     return returnString;
                         }
```